# How do I prevent my pointer for an array element from being reassigned

Tags: c

I'm pretty new to C so maybe I'm using pointers incorrectly. I'm working on a larger program and where I'm running into an issue where a pointer, pointing at the first element of an array is constantly changing as the array changes (using a PriorityQueue, so it's constantly being rearranged and so I'm running into issues).

I've made a very basic example of what's going on:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    
    int testArray[] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
    
    int *pFirstElement = &testArray[0];
    
    printf("My first element: %d\n", *pFirstElement); // Prints 0
    
    testArray[0] = 9;
    
    printf("My first element: %d", *pFirstElement); // Prints 9 -> I want it to print 0
    
    return 0;
    
}
```

I'd like a way so that pFirstElement does not get reassigned until I manually reassign pFirstElement to be the first element of the array. Basically, modifications to the array should not change the value of pFirstElement. Is it because a pointer is pointing to the memory address of `testArray[0]`, and instead should I not be using a Pointer?

The reason I used a pointer is that I can initialize it to NULL, and then a use case for my PriorityQueue is if the pointer is NULL, I know I need to dequeue basically. Not sure how else I could do that logic.

Any advice is helpful, thanks!

Comment: Currently this reads like "I want my program to behave incorrectly." Please explain why you think that your code should print an unchanged value in spite of the fact that you changed it in between.

Comment: You have a pointer to the first element. You don't change it. It doesn't change. You change the first element, then the first element changes. You don't have to do anything to prevent it from being reassigned. If you don't want the value of the first element to change, don't change it. Are you by any chance a Java or C# programmer? C is a different language & things work differently.

Comment: I change the first element because in my actual code, the elements are constantly changing (I have an array implmenetation of a Priority Queue). So I don't want my value *pFirstElement* to be changed UNTIL I change that myself. I'd like to modify the contents of the array without having *pFirstElement* change from *0*, until I do something like *pFirstElement = dequeue(myArray)*. I'm super new to C so I'd like to know if instead of a pointer, I should be using a normal variable. To answer @AviBerger, yeah I mainly use Java so I'm a bit confused

Comment: `int firstElement = testArray[0];` Now you can change `testArray[0]` and `firstElement` remains unchanged.

Comment: If you want to maintain the value of a variable as 0 until you change it, then, yes, use a variable. A pointer is like a handle to another variable. You use a handle to open a drawer, you get whatever is currently in the drawer. If you change what is in the drawer, you get the new contents.

Comment: This seems to indicate you've got a wobbly understanding of what a pointer is, which can be something a lot of new C programmers have to go through. Remember: A pointer **does not hold data**, it only holds a *pointer* to data stored somewhere else. Creating pointer to something does not make a copy. In C you will almost always have to explicitly copy something to make that happen, as in with `memcpy()` or other tools.

Comment: Culture shock then. C operates closer to the machine. Java sticks in layers of stuff between you and that level, so what you see from a Java perspective includes built up constructs that aren't there in plain C.

Answer (score 1):

Since `pFirstElement` is simply a *reference* to the memory in which first element of the array is stored, reassigning the first element of the array will change the value that `pFirstElement` is pointing to.

Setting an `int` variable instead of an `int *` to `testArray[0]` instead of `&testArray[0]` will create a copy of the data instead of simply storing a new reference to it. The copy is now independent of the data in `testArray`.

Creating a copy of the data is the only way. A pointer by itself cannot remember past values of the memory it points to.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `pFirstElement` points to the position in memory, where the first array element is. If you now access the value the pointer points to, you access the first element of the array. If you simply want a copy of first element use `int firstElement = testArray[0];`, otherwise `*pFirstElement = ...` is equivalent to `textArray[0] = ...`.